# HTML button and php file

Tags: php, python, html

I have a website that I created and I need to have a button link to a php file for it to execute a python script. My problem is that when you click the button the script does not execute.
 This is what I have so far, anything will help! The php file is called minecraft.php and the python script is called py-mine.py.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/py-mine.py');
?>
```

and a section of my html for the button:

```
<a href="minecraft.php">
<button class="bkg-navy-light border-hover-navy-light color-white color-hover-navy-light no-margin-left" ></a>
    <span class="icon-upload"></span>
        Minecraft
    </button>
<input type="submit" value="Button3" class="form-submit button medium bkg-black bkg-hover-turquoise color-white color-hover-white">
```

Comment: And what isn't working?  It looks like you have a *link* to that file, so that should work just fine.  Does it?  Why do you need a button instead of that link?  Is your button working?

Comment: When you click the button, nothing happens. The script doesn't execute and I wasn't sure how to do that. First time using php

Comment: Assuming you have an `echo $output` somewhere in the page to show this output to someone, your problem is one of HTML, not PHP. You've closed your `<a>` inside your `<button>`

Comment: Agree with @miken32, although it can be a typo in the question only. Better check it first.

Comment: thanks for the catch on the <a>, but I don't have any output to really display when the button is clicked. The py-mine.py script spins up an aws ubuntu instance and runs commands to install minecraft on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly structure the HTML code:

You can use a `hyperlink`:

```
<a href="minecraft.php">A link to the PHP page</a>
```

**OR**

Use a `button`:

```
<form action="minecraft.php" method="GET">
    <button class="bkg-navy-light border-hover-navy-light color-white color-hover-navy-light no-margin-left" type="submit">
        <span class="icon-upload"></span>
        A button to the PHP page
    </button>
</form>
```

In your current code you used mix of both with wrong syntax structure.

Make sure you use *one* option.

Also, your php shell_exec should call a shell `command`, which in your case should be `python`:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('python /var/www/html/py-mine.py');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the changed but it still doesn't work. Is there something I need as in a line of code to make the php file work ?

Comment: @compma : Sure, How I did forget this !. you should call a `python` command. Don't forget the **python** keyword before *.py file path

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but what is the command used for that?

Comment: the command `python` is called so that it runs the python script `.py` file. The python script file can not run by itself without the `python` command.